# Upper right Dini derivative and indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand how the proof of the theorem below works. (Theorem 13.26, Real Analysis, J. Yeh, 2nd ed.)

> Let $f$ be a real-valued continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that $f'$ exists almost everywhere (a.e.)  and $f'$ is $\mu_L$-integrable on [a,b]. If the upper-right Dini derivative $D^+f > -\infty$, on [a,b), then we have
> $$
> \int\limits_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L=f(x)-f(a)
> $$  for every $x\in[a,b]$.

The proof goes like this.
 The author defines additional functions. 
$$
\begin{split}
g_n(x) &=\min\{f'(x),n\},\quad G_n=\int\limits_{[a,x]}g_nd\mu_L \\
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}G_n &=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{[a,x]}g_nd\mu_L=\int\limits_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L
\end{split} \text{ for }x\in[a,b]
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}
h_n(x)&=\max\{f'(x),-n\},\quad H_n=\int\limits_{[a,x]}h_nd\mu_L \\ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}H_n&=\lim\limits\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_{[a,x]}h_nd\mu_L=\int\limits_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L 
\end{split}\text{ for }x\in[a,b]
$$
Then,
$$
D^+G_n(x)=\limsup\limits_{h\downarrow0}h^{-1}\int\limits_{[x,x+h]}g_nd\mu_L\le\limsup\limits_{h\downarrow0}h^{-1}\int\limits_{[x,x+h]}n\mu_L=n,
$$ and
$$
D^+(f-G_n)\ge D^+f-D^+G_n\gt -\infty
$$ (in addition to $\ge 0$ a.e.), because $D^+f > -\infty$ by supposition, and $D^+G_n\le n$.
Thus, the real valued continuous function $f-G_n$ is an increasing function, and
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)-G_n(x)-(f(a)-G_n(a))&\ge0,\\
f(x)-f(a)&\ge G_n(x)
\end{align}
$$  for $x\in[a,b)$.
Since this holds for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
f(x)-f(a)\ge\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}G_n(x)=\int_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L.$$
Also,
$$
\begin{split}
D^+H_n(x) & = \limsup\limits_{h\downarrow0}h^{-1}\int_{[x,x+h]}h_nd\mu_L \\ 
& \ge \limsup\limits_{h\downarrow0}h^{-1}\int_{[x,x+h]}-n\mu_L=-n
\end{split}
$$ and
$$
D^+(H_n-f)\ge D^+H_n-D^+f\gt -\infty
$$ (and $\ge 0$ a.e.), because
$$
D^+f > -\infty\text{ and }D^+H_n\ge -n. \label{1}\tag{$***$}
$$
Thus, $H_n-f$ is an increasing function, and
$$
\begin{split}
H_n(x)&-f(x)-(H_n(a)-f(a)) \ge0,\\
H_n(x)&\ge f(x)-f(a)\\
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}H_n(x)&=\int_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L\ge f(x)-f(a)
\end{split}
$$ for $x\in[a,b)$.
Finally,
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L &\ge f(x)-f(a)\ge\int_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L,\\
\int_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L & = f(x)-f(a).
\end{split}
$$
I'm stuck at the line marked by \eqref{1}
How does $D^+f > -\infty$ and $D^+H_n\ge -n$ mean $D^+H_n-D^+f\gt -\infty$?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a counterexample to the quoted claim:

> "Let $f$ be a real-valued continuous function on [a,b] such that $f'$ exists almost everywhere (a.e.)  and $f'$ is $\mu_L$-integrable on [a,b]. If the upper-right Dini derivative $D^+f > -\infty$, on [a,b), then we have $\int_{[a,x]}f'd\mu_L=f(x)-f(a)$  for every $x\in[a,b]$."

Indeed, let $f$ be the Cantor function. Then $f$ is a real-valued continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $f'=0$ a.e., so that $f'$ is $\mu_L$-integrable on $[0,1]$. Since $f$ in nondecreasing, we have
$D^+f \ge0> -\infty$ on $[0,1)$. However,
$$
\int\limits_{[0,1]}f'd\mu_L=0\ne1-0=f(1)-f(0).
$$

---

Of course, the logical transition that you marked by ($***$) is also wrong.